About the index of an inverse limit related to the tame inertia group
Let me begin with the context: $p$ is a prime number. We consider the extensions
$$ \mathbb{Q}_p\subset \mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}\subset \mathbb{Q}_p^{tm}\subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p,$$
where $\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}$ is the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p^{tm}$ is the maximal tamely ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Define the tame inertia group as
$$ I_p^{tm}=\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p^{tm}/\mathbb{Q}_p^{unr}).$$
I am trying to identy $I_p^{tm}$ with two inverse limits.
(1) Denote ${\mu}_d$ the group of $d$-th roots of unity  in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. If $d$ and $d'$ are positive integers coprime to $p$ such that $d\mid d'$, consider the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
f_{dd'}\colon {\mu}_{d'}&\to{\mu}_d\\
    \zeta_{d'}&\mapsto\zeta_{d'}^{d'/d}.
\end{align*}
Then, $({\mu}_d,f_{dd'})$ is an inverse system indexed by the integers coprime to $p$, with the partial order given by divisibility. By a previous result about finite tamely ramified extensions (the result is: if $K/\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}$ is a tamely ramified extension of degree $d$, then it is Galois with Galois group isomorphic to $\mu_d$) then I can identity
$$ I_p^{tm}\cong \varprojlim \mu_d, $$
with $d$ running every positive integer coprime to $p$. If someone can confirm to me that this is right, I'd be glad, but I think I get this part until now.
(2) If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $m\mid n$, consider the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
    N_{mn}\colon \mathbb{F}_{p^n}^\times&\to\mathbb{F}_{p^m}^\times\\
    x&\mapsto x^{1+q+\dots+q^{n-1}},
\end{align*}
where $q=p^m$. Then, I thought that  $(\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times,N_{mn})$ is an inverse system indexed by the positive integers. My advisor told me that $m$ and $n$ must be coprime to $p$, but I don't understand why. We are following this article (https://wstein.org/sage_summer/bsd_comp/Serre-properties_galoisiennes_des_points_dordre_fini_des_courbes_elliptiques.pdf), page 6 and 7. For me, it seems that $m$ and $n$ need not be coprime to $p$, but the reasoning I did to show $I_p^{tm}\cong \varprojlim \mathbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$, taking $n$ over all positive integers made me doubt about the index. This reasoning is the following:
One only needs to show that the inverse systems  $({\mu}_d,f_{dd'})$ and $(\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times,N_{mn})$ are equivalent. It's clear that for every positive $n$, we have $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^\times\cong {\mu}_{p^n-1}, $
since both of them are cyclic groups of order $p^n-1$. One only needs to show that the set
$$S=\{d\in\mathbb Z: d\geq1, \gcd(d,p)=1\} $$
is cofinal in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. (Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. $B$ is cofinal in $A$ if $B\subset A$ if for every $a\in A$, there exists $b\in B$ such that $a\mid b$.)
For every $d\in S$, there exists an integer $n\geq1$ such that $p^n-1\equiv 0\bmod{d}$. Indeed, by Euler's theorem, one can take $n=\varphi(d)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. Therefore, $d\mid p^n-1$.
What I am proving here is that the inverse system $(\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times,N_{mn})$  should be indexed by the numbers of the form $p^n-1$, for every integer $n\geq 1$. I'd be glad if someone could tell me if this is correct or incorrect.
Thank you very much in advance.

For (1) there is a nice treatment of this on the stacks project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09EE. Yes it agrees with what you say.

The result you parenthetically cite in (1) does not agree with what you say. That result you cite is incorrect since tamely ramified $K/\mathbf Q_p$ need not even be Galois: the field $K = \mathbf Q_p(p^{1/(p+1)})$ has $e(K/\mathbf Q_p) = p+1 \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$, so $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is tamely ramified, and $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is not Galois.  Instead, you really want the base field to be $\mathbf Q_p^{nr}$ since that contains $d$th roots of unity for all $d$ relatively prime to $p$.

@KConrad Sorry, of course that is true. I actually meant the result you are saying, but I made mistake writing "$\mathbb{Q}_p$" instead of $\mathbb{Q}^{nr}_p$ in the question, I will edit it. Thanks
